# SQS subscribed to multiple SNS with different data models

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

**Context**

I have 2 SNS both publishing messages with different data model.
I want a lambda to get these messages and do some processing.
Creating a SQS between the SNS and Lambda is mandatory.

**What i thought of?**

I will create 2 new SQS to subscribe to the 2 SNS. One SQS will subscribe to only 1 SNS.
I will create 2 new Lambda to read from 2 SQS and process the messages.

**What i am looking for ?**

Is there a way to create only 1 SQS and subscribe to both SNS and create 1 Lambda to read from the 1 SQS. Asking this because creating 2 lambda and SQS is costly. The major issue is both SNS have different data model. Is there a way to overcome this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both topics deliver their messages into the same Queue and then use a single Lambda to read from that.

If you **disable** raw message delivery ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html)), the Event will include information about the topic the Event is from, which allows you to distinguish between the two event types in your Lambda code and handle them separately.